# Android RTL form API 10 to API 21

Tags: android-layout, localization, arabic-support

I have to build an app with both support for english and arabic layouts, the working range is from api 10 (2.3.3) to api 21 (5.0).

Following [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) document I configured the app, but I cannot use "start" and "end" because the range of support is too wide.

I thought I can create a layout folder like "layout-16" where to put all layouts with "start" and "end" for versions from 4.2, and another like "layout-ar" where to put all the mirrored layouts for versions before api16.

It could work like that? Or the "layouts-ar" will override the "layout-16"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since the language is has a bigger priority than the app version, I should advice to have several folder like:

- **layout-v16** for all your layout that support start/end
- **layout-ar-v16** empty folder to force the system to use layouts-16.
- **layout-ar** for arabic and android under the version 16.
- **layout** for standard layouts.

Good luck !